# How do I use a large amount of worksheets in excel without knowing the exact number?

Tags: vba, excel

I have well over 100 worksheets I am trying to macro for.  Rather than sitting here and counting every singe one to get a count, is there a way to include all worksheets starting at a certain point and going through the rest of them?  I only need to include worksheets 18 through the end.

Here is my code

```
Sub Conversion()
For y = 18 To (END????)
    For x = 1 To 30
    testvalue1 = Worksheets(y).Cells(x, 4)
        If testvalue1 <> "" Then
            If IsNumeric(testvalue1) Then
                Worksheets(y).Cells(x, 4) = (Worksheets(y).Cells(x, 4) + 5500)
                testvalue2 = Worksheets(y).Cells(x, 4)
            End If
        End If
    Next x
Next y
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have a collection of *things* in VBA they are often likely to implement a `.count` property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
For y = 18 To Worksheets.Count
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also work on `each` worksheet in a workbook.

```
Dim ws as worksheet
For each ws in ThisWorkbook
    If ws.index >= 18 then
        ' do stuff to every worksheet past index 18
    End if
Next ws
```

It's just another alternative. It's not very useful in this specific case, but very useful when you want to do something to *every* worksheet.